# Connecting to a Local SQL Server Instance with instance name from Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I am trying to access a local SQL Server from Data Factory.  I have installed the Integration Runtime on a local box, which also has a SQL Instance, but it's DEV, so not really a problem.

So VMs involved are:

**A** - Local SQL Server and Integration Runtime installed (localhost)

**B** - Local SQL Server without Instance name (ServerName.somesite.com)

**C** - Local SQL Server with Instance name (ServerName\InstanceName.somesite.com)

I have successfully tested to make sure connections work to both the local box **A** and local box **B**, no problems.  However when trying to access the SQL Server with the instance name from Data Factory, I got the error: "provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified"

I have checked the UDP Port 1434 issue, the port was opened on the local machine. Can Data Factory not connect to local servers with an instance name? If so, is there a workaround? (I am thinking an ODBC DSN on the local IR host or similar).

Even when trying to test this from the IR configuration manager, I get this:

[image: IRError]

Comment: what's the instance name? Actually, the 'ServerName\InstanceName.somesite.com' format is not correct. The instance name = ServerName. We only can use one, localhost or the Server/instance name.

Comment: You couldn't have tested that the hostname works because it's in an incorrect format. It's more like `host.something.something\instance`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - OK, I will try that syntax when I get back to work, thanks.

Comment: @LeonYue - should the connection syntax from Data Factory be similar to what Nick wrote?

Comment: that server name format isn't valid _anywhere_.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I can confirm that syntax works.  Please put your comment as an answer and I will mark it as one (should hopefully help others that have the same issue).

Comment: @blobbles yeah, that's right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks@Nick.McDermaid, as he said:

1. To access a local SQL Server from Data Factory the syntanx is like this `host.something.something\instance` .
2. When the database instance is bound to another port number, we can use the syntax like this
   `host.something.something\instance,port number`